# How can I explode takes from a region onto a single track in Logic Pro X?

Tags: logic-pro

How can I explode takes from a region onto a single track?

For example: I record over a 1 bar loop, N number of times. I then explode the takes to create a new region that is N bars long.

This is something that was a big part of my workflow in Ableton Live. I find it useful for writing/improvising riffs of arbitrary length, before the development of the song structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the Project list (choose View ▶ Browsers and tap on Project) you will see that your take recording created one audio file. Underneath that audio file in the Project list are the regions that have been created for that audio file. Each individual take is stored as one region. Logic’s regions are analogous to clips in Ableton Live.

So if you did 4 takes, you will see a structure like this in the Project list:

```
Audio File Name  
* [take 1 region]  
* [take 2 region]  
* [take 3 region]  
* [take 4 region]
```

If you want to use those regions consecutively, just select all of them (select the first one, hold down Shift, then select the last one) and drag them onto an audio track. Logic will show a dialog that asks you how you want those regions to be placed onto the track — select “place all files on one track.”

On the track you will then see this kind of structure:

```
[take 1 region] [take 2 region] [take 3 region] [take 4 region]
```

… which you can use as-is or optionally join into one region.